# Is every closed subgroup of dual group an annihilator?

Tags: topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

This is a naive question as I am new to topological group theory.

Let $G$ be a Locally Compact Abelian group (LCA group).

I know that to every closed subgroup $H$ of $G$ correspond a closed subgroup in the dual group $\widehat{G}$, namely the annihilator of $H$ - that is the set of all characters $\gamma$ over $G$ such that $\gamma(h) = 1$ for all $h \in H$.

My question is this : is there a one-to-one correspondance between the closed subgroups of $G$ and the closed subgroups of the dual group $\widehat{G}$ ? Is every closed subgroup of $\widehat{G}$ an annihilator for some closed subgroup $H$ of $G$ ?

Comment: Cross-posted on MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191313/is-every-closed-subgroup-of-dual-group-an-annihilator.

Comment: @Alex M. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by Theorem 53 from [Pon] each closed subgroup of LCA group is the annihilator of its annihilator.

[Pon] Lev S. Pontrjagin, *Continuous groups*, 2nd ed., M., (1954) (in Russian).